# Accessing the localdatabase using android emulator

Tags: php, android, json, authentication, registration

I am working with http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/  . I am facing several problems here tagging with JSON . I don't know what to do now. I want to add that my local host is ar port 81. and i have just only changed localhost:81/android_login_api/ and localhost:81/android_login_api/ in the login and registration url respectivly.  here is my logcat error -

```
02-24 11:17:58.000: E/JSON(1364): <br />
02-24 11:17:58.000: E/JSON(1364): <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected $end in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\include\DB_Connect.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />
02-24 11:17:58.011: E/JSON Parser(1364): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-24 11:17:58.011: D/AndroidRuntime(1364): Shutting down VM
02-24 11:17:58.011: W/dalvikvm(1364): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.example.androidhive.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:64)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-24 11:17:58.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my php code --

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
               uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
               unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
               name varchar(50) not null,
               email varchar(100) not null unique,
               encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
               salt varchar(10) not null,
               created_at datetime,
               updated_at datetime null
            );
      mysql_query($sql);

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $con;
    }

    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your file `C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\include\DB_Connect.php` contains a syntax error. Your server returns a HTML-site (with information on this error) instead of a JSON-encoded result-String.

The JSONParser expects something like `"{somedata:true}"` but gets `<br />` and other HTML-Tags and then throws a `JSONException` which ends up in returning `null` (which itself causes the `NullPointerException`)

You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376645/org-json-jsonexception-value-br-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-t).

Comment: Thanks but i don't understand what they try to say. What the solution is? i Like to say that my localhost address i set it 10.0.2.2

Comment: This isn't really a solution but rather a hint to where your error may come from. Can you post the content of the file I mentioned above (or at least the lines around line 46)? This might help finding the syntax error

Comment: in my php file that is the ending. in line 46

Comment: So 46 is the last line of your script? Maybe you forgot to close a bracket (like `(` or `{`). It's really hard to tell if there is a syntax error in your file if you don't post its content in your question.

Comment: i have added the php code. You can also see the whole content by clicking the link that i have already posted in my question

Comment: private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2:81/android_login_api/";
 private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2:81/android_login_api/";
 
 private static String login_tag = "login";
 private static String register_tag = "register";

Comment: If this isn't a typo from copy&paste, you're not closing the string saved in the `$sql` variable (which is easy to see with the syntax-highlighting from stackoverflow). Closing this String should eliminate your syntax error.