# android connecting with php /mysql using json the select query do not work

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, error-handling

i am creating a simple android application that add user (register)  and retrieve user(login)

the first action work perfectly but the second force close and crush the application.

can anyone help me???

## logCat

```
04-02 08:24:18.532: E/JSON Parser(2380): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-02 08:24:18.536: W/dalvikvm(2380): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c06648)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at com.example.dvr.MainActivity$login.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:123)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at com.example.dvr.MainActivity$login.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-02 08:24:18.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     ... 4 more
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380): Activity com.example.dvr.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52e3cf88 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.dvr.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52e3cf88 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at com.example.dvr.MainActivity$login.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:96)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at com.example.dvr.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-02 08:24:19.868: E/WindowManager(2380):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- **php code:**

## 1)db_config.php

```
<?php

/*
 * All database connection variables
 */

define('DB_USER', "********"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "*********"); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "databse"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
?>
```

## 2)adduser.php

```
 <?php

    /*
     * Following code will create a new product row
     * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
     */

    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();

    // check for required fields
    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {

        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];


        // include db connect class
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(user, password) VALUES('$user', '$password')");

        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

## 3)login.php

```
<?php
//array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    // include db connect class
    require_once '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $sql = mysql_query("Select user, password from users where user='$user'")or die(mysql_error());
    $count_query = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($sql){
     $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Wrong User Or Pass";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
     else{
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "correct Informations";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}   
?>
```

**the Error is in the login action how to fix this error i need it to work.**

- **android code:**

## 1) JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.dvr;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

## 2)MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dvr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText username_edt;
    EditText pass_edt;

    // url to creaate new product
    private static String url_create_user = "http://10.0.3.2/android_connect/adduser.php";
    private static String url_login_user = "http://10.0.3.2/android_connect/login.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Edit Text
        username_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pass_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        // inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });

        // Login button
        Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        // button click event
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new login().execute();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        username_edt.toString() + pass_edt.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Selecting Users
     * */

    class login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String user = username_edt.getText().toString();
            String password = pass_edt.getText().toString();
            // String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login_user,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
        //  Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    finish();

                } else {
                    // failed
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String user = username_edt.getText().toString();
            String password = pass_edt.getText().toString();
            // String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_user,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    finish();

                } else {
                    // failed
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is line no:123 in MainActivity.?

Comment: i think Your String is JSONArray not JSONObject you need to get JSONObject from JSONArray.

Comment: @ SilentKiller this is the line 123 **int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);**

Comment: can you show us a demo preview of your json string, print it in LOG and put it here

Answer (score 0):

Use address 10.0.2.2 instead 10.0.3.2

```
private static String url_create_user = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/adduser.php";
private static String url_login_user = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/login.php";
```

Comment: no the addresses are correct because  i am using genymotion emulator

Answer (score 0):

i was able to  some how fix the error by adding a simple **Log.i()** before the creation of the new JSONObject  and it show me that i have an error in the login.php file at line 20

i solved this question by referring to this solution [org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376645/org-json-jsonexception-value-br-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-t)