# java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONArray Android Mysql

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask, android-notifications

I'm trying to push Notifications of Book On Due today for my library Mobile app but after I log in this error pops up in my app.

> 4:run java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONArray.

My PHP is working fine but how can I fix this error?

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
W/System.err:     at com.example.ivan.librarymobileapp.backWorkerNotif.doInBackground(backWorkerNotif.java:67)
W/System.err:     at com.example.ivan.librarymobileapp.backWorkerNotif.doInBackground(backWorkerNotif.java:23)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here's my code:

**backWorkerNotif Class**

```
public class backWorkerNotif extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
   String result = null;
   String[] BookTittle;
   Context context;
   public  backWorkerNotif(Context context){this.context = context;}

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      String selectNotif_url = "http://192.168.254.120/LibrayAPI/SelectNotif.php";
      String type = params[0];

      if (type.equals("Notif")) {
        String DateNow = params[1];
        String BorrowerID = params[2];
        try {

          String data = URLEncoder.encode("date_now", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(DateNow, "UTF-8");
                data += "$" + URLEncoder.encode("borrower_id", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(BorrowerID, "UTF-8");

               URL url = new URL(selectNotif_url);
               URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
               urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

               OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

               outputStreamWriter.write(data);
               outputStreamWriter.flush();

               BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               String line;
               while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                 sb.append(line + "\n");
               }
               result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception ex) {


            }
            //Json
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                BookTittle = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                for (int i = 0;i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    BookTittle[i] = jsonObject.getString("BookTittle");

                    NotificationCompat.Builder  mbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_book_black_24dp)
                            .setContentTitle("Library notification")
                            .setContentText("Today is the Due Day of"+ BookTittle[i] +"You Borrowed");
                    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0,mbuilder.build())
                }   
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonArray) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonArray);
    }
}
```

**Log In Classs**

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username,password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
        password = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    }

    public void onLogin(View view) {

        String Username = username.getText().toString();
        String Password = password.getText().toString();
        backWorkerNotif backWorkerNotif = new backWorkerNotif(this);
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat SF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String DateNow = SF.format(date);
        backWorkerNotif.execute("Notif", DateNow, Username);

        String Type = "login";
        GlobalVariable.BorrowerID = Username;
        backgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new backgroundWorker(this);
        _backgroundWorker.execute(Type, Username, Password);
    }
}
```

**My php Code**

```
<?php
require "Connection.php";
$DateNow = $_POST["date_now"];
$BorrowerID = $_POST["borrower_id"];

$query = "SELECT A.`BookId`,B.`BookTittle`,A.`BorrowerId` FROM `tblborrow` AS A INNER JOIN `tblbooks` AS B ON A.`BookId` = B.`BookId` WHERE `DueDate` = '$DateNow' AND `BorrowerId` = '$BorrowerID'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($e = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[] = $e;
}
echo json_encode($output);
print (json_encode($output));
?>
```

**The result from my PHP**

```
[
  {"BookId":"101","BookTittle":"Counting dolars","BorrowerId":"11"},
  {"BookId":"9876","BookTittle":"ihi","BorrowerId":"11"},
  {"BookId":"542","BookTittle":"hiragana","BorrowerId":"11"},
  {"BookId":"5421","BookTittle":"wow","BorrowerId":"11"}
][
  {"BookId":"101","BookTittle":"Counting dolars","BorrowerId":"11"},
  {"BookId":"9876","BookTittle":"ihi","BorrowerId":"11"},  
  {"BookId":"542","BookTittle":"hiragana","BorrowerId":"11"},  
  {"BookId":"5421","BookTittle":"wow","BorrowerId":"11"}
]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is happening because something is going wrong with your php script output. Try to run this script i postman.

Comment: Whats the format of the result ? Can you share please

Comment: And you should use that result in ‘onPostExucute()’

Comment: May be its because I use echo and print on my php?

Comment: [{"BookId":"101","BookTittle":"Counting dolars","BorrowerId":"11"},{"BookId":"9876","BookTittle":"ihi","BorrowerId":"11"},{"BookId":"542","BookTittle":"hiragana","BorrowerId":"11"},{"BookId":"5421","BookTittle":"wow","BorrowerId":"11"}][{"BookId":"101","BookTittle":"Counting dolars","BorrowerId":"11"},{"BookId":"9876","BookTittle":"ihi","BorrowerId":"11"},{"BookId":"542","BookTittle":"hiragana","BorrowerId":"11"},{"BookId":"5421","BookTittle":"wow","BorrowerId":"11"}]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376645/org-json-jsonexception-value-br-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-t)

Comment: you likely receive not a JSONArray as a response for some reason

Comment: found it in my   String data = URLEncoder.encode("date_now", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(DateNow, "UTF-8");
                data += "$" + URLEncoder.encode("borrower_id", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(BorrowerID, "UTF-8");
$ suppose to & but its only pushing the last data in my notification

Comment: okey it good now

Answer (score 0):

as Exception says you have received `<br` value in response which is not json format.

put "application/json" as header for your request content-type. but this is not guarantee that your code will always work. by doing so you only make sure that you will receive response  in json format.

the problem is about format of output stream. if your connection get any type of HTTP exception or other type of errors, you will not get aware, since you swallow it. change it in this way:

```
try {

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("date_now", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(DateNow, "UTF-8");
                data += "$" + URLEncoder.encode("borrower_id", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(BorrowerID, "UTF-8");

                URL url = new URL(selectNotif_url);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

                outputStreamWriter.write(data);
                outputStreamWriter.flush();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                //JSON
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                BookTittle = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                for (int i = 0;i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    BookTittle[i] = jsonObject.getString("BookTittle");

                    NotificationCompat.Builder  mbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_book_black_24dp)
                            .setContentTitle("Library notification")
                            .setContentText("Today is the Due Day of"+ BookTittle[i] +"You Borrowed");
                    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0,mbuilder.build());


                }


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please provide us with sample out put which you receive from php. I mean the `result` value

Comment: I cant see the difference between my code with your code

Comment: I have merged two try-catch blocks into one block

Comment: } catch (Exception ex) {


            }
            //Json
            try {          are removed

Comment: okey  thankyou .found the issue the $ is supposed to be & in my UrlEncoder

Comment: I have another question sir .

Comment: How can I call my asyntask every day even my app is close?

Comment: the following link would be help full: => https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android